# Android - How to use one record (cursor) to populate data for multiple list items in ListView?

Tags: android, fragment, android-cursoradapter

Does anyone know how to achieve the below requirement?

When the database is queried, there is only one record returned.
This record will be used to populate few list item in ListView (say 5 entries).

Since it's only one record, I am facing difficulties to populate entries for second up to fifth entries.

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    public TestCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
            list.add("Test 1");
            list.add("Test 2");
            list.add("Test 3");
            list.add("Test 4");
            list.add("Test 5");
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
           // cursor will only return one record, but it needs to populate five records (list size is 5)
    }         

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
           // cursor will only return one record, but it needs to populate five records (list size is 5)
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 5;
    }
}
```

I am using `CursorLoader` to query data from database.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? What data must be used to "populate entries for second up to fifth entries" if only one record is returned? Need "mock" data, or something used to just fill record 2-5 of you listview?

Answer (score 0):

`CursorAdapter` is only suited to `Cursors` of a particular format, with one row per row in the `ListView`.  You'd be better off writing your own custom extension of [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) whose backing data is your unique `Cursor`.  Then you can specify exactly how to get the data for each position in [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).